# Problem with adding procedure and error with invalid object name

Tags: sql-server, object, procedure

My first question: How to add the following procedure to the "Programmability-> Stored Procedures" folder.

```
USE [Tournaments]
GO

SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[spPrizes_Insert]
    @PlaceNumber int,
    @PlaceName nvarchar(50),
    @PrizeAmount money,
    @PrizePercentage float,
    @id int = 0 output
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    insert into dbo.Prizes (PlaceNumber, PlaceName, PrizeAmount, PrizePercentage)
    values (@PlaceNumber, @PlaceName, @PrizeAmount, @PrizePercentage);

    select @id = SCOPE_IDENTITY();

END
```

and second question - I have error:

> Msg 208, Level 16, State 6, Procedure spPrizes_Insert, Line 9
> Invalid object name 'dbo.spPrizes_Insert'.

Why?

Comment: Q1. Its automatic, SQL Server will list all SPs there. Q2. You can't use alter until it exists, change alter to create the first time.

Comment: It is POINTLESS to define a default value for your output parameter.

Comment: @DaleK SQL Server, your second answer resolve the problem :-) thanks

Comment: If you're on a recent version of SQL Server, then use `CREATE OR ALTER`.

Comment: Side note, I hope you're column for `PrizePercentage` isn't a `float`; `float` is an imprecise data type and percentages tend to need to be precise when working with money.